# Forbidden or allowed? $\rho_0\to \pi_0\eta$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model

I have to determine whether the neutral rho meson could decay into a neutral pion and eta. I have checked the quantum numbers and all of them seem to be conserved adding an orbital angular momentum to the pion-eta system.

Nevertheless, this reaction seems not to be allowed and I was wondering if this could be because the rho meson doesn't have enough energy to provide angular momentum to the system. Is this correct?

Comment: So, you have checked *C* and *G*?

Comment: You can find the quantum numbers here , under light mesons, http://pdg.lbl.gov/2013/listings/contents_listings.html . this might help http://www.fe.infn.it/~bettoni/particelle/Symmetries2.pdf

Comment: If it was allowed, shouldn't it be listed in the PDG rho decay modes?  Or depentds of the fraction? (http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/tables/rpp2014-sum-mesons.pdf)

Comment: The PDG tends not to list decay modes that haven't been seen or had limits set on them. The decay $\rho^0 \to \pi^+ \pi^- \pi^0 \pi^0$ has been observed, so I see no reason why $\rho^0 \to \eta \pi^0$ should be forbidden

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this decay via the strong interaction is not allowed due to violation of G-parity, as @Cosmas Zachos hinted in a comment, but it is probably allowed via the electromagnetic interaction, but such decay may be difficult to observe as rho decays very fast via the strong interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,I have done the following:

Initial information:
rho_0: I^G(J^{PC}) = 1+(1--)
eta:   I^G(J^{PC}) = 0+(0-+)
pi_0:  I^G(J^{PC}) = 1-(1--)

*Angular momentum:
J_rho = 1  J_eta_pi = 0 then we need additional angular orbital momentum to conserve the momentum. I assume L = 1.

- Parity: 
  J_rho = (-)  J_eta_pi = (-)(-)(-)^L = (-)
- Charge conjugation:
  C_rho = (-)  C_eta_pi = (+)(+)(-)^L = (-)
- I tried even G-parity too:
  G_rho = (+) G_eta_pi = (+)(-)(-)^L+S+I = (+)

My guess is that maybe, the mass of rho (~775MeV) is not enough to give angular momentum to the system (m_pion=140MeV; m_eta~550MeV), but I don´t know how to check it.

Cheers, 
Ateniger

Comment: G of eta is + G of pion is - , G of rho is + . See https://books.google.gr/books?id=PbE3BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=G+parity+of+a+system+of+particles&source=bl&ots=kU7ru8d3rO&sig=sRKkrYTla2ByZT8ztSIGj9eUCVo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjc9Z-FktPQAhVCORoKHRd3AwgQ6AEISzAH#v=onepage&q=G%20parity%20of%20a%20system%20of%20particles&f=false  . "the G parity of a system of particles each of which has a definite G parity is equal to the product of the G parities of the separate particles". G parity is conserved in strong decay, so this could only be electromagnetic, which will be down by powers of 1/137

Comment: The above point suggests that your additional mysterious antisymmetrizer $(-)^{L+S+I}$ is distinctly unsound: *G* just counts pions and it is as good as isospin, violated by electromagnetism, but not the strong interactions. @dukwon alerts you to the equivalent 4π mode, electromagnetic, except there you do not need to reconstruct the η.